# copy data from one list to another using workflow

Tags: designer-workflow

There are two lists, one person has permission on the list1 and no permission to the list list2, now he has to copy data from list1 to list2 using workflows.

Comment: Please provide more information like the workflow Platform type 2010/2013.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**:

You can create a workflow with elevated permissions using **App Step** as user is not having permission on list 2.

**References**:

1. [Create a workflow with elevated permissions by using the SharePoint Workflow](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/create-a-workflow-with-elevated-permissions-by-using-the-sharepoint-workflo).

**Note**: column structure of both lists should be same in order to copy list items from one list to another.